# CURL и редирект

Tags: php, curl, redirect, редирект

При помощи cURLa тыкаюсь на страницу XML.
Если этой страницы не существует, то происходит редирект на красиво оформленную 404 страничку.
В итоге SimpleXML выдаёт ошибку, что XML невалидный.
Вопрос: как определить, что cURL получил страницу 404, а не XML файл?
Или может есть какой ещё способ..?

Код прилагаю:

```
$ch = curl_init($xml_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$xml_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Ага. Спасибо. Впрочем не особо помогло, так как тыкается на код 200 ОК. Буду тогда парсером определять наличие тех или иных параметров для определения XML валидного.

Answer (score 0):

Выставьте опцию для `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=false` и оне не будет редиректится, если это действительно редирект.

Comment: Немножко не то. Но спасибо. Информация пригодится.